# SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient for two streams against same Socket fails

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, tls1.2, sslstream

I've had a design where one `Socket` has **two** `NetworkStream` opened: one for *reads* and one for *writes*.

When updating the code to start using `SslStreams` a call to `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync` yields an error for the second stream (order is not relevant).

> Win32Exception: The token supplied to the function is invalid

**Q:** Is there a way to have two active and authenticated `SslStream` against one `Socket`?

Sample code:

```
NetworkStream readStream = socket.CreateReadWriteStream();
NetworkStream writeStream = socket.CreateReadWriteStream();

var sslR = new SslStream(readStream, false, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback, null, EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption);
var sslW = new SslStream(writeStream, false, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback, null, EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption);

var clientAuthOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
{
    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = RemoteCertificateValidationCallback,
    AllowRenegotiation = true,
    CertificateRevocationCheckMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
    ClientCertificates = connectionInfo.ClientCertificates,
    EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
    EncryptionPolicy = EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption,
    TargetHost = host.Address
};

//Suceeds
await sslR.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(clientAuthOptions, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

//Fails
await sslW.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(clientAuthOptions, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Authentication requires bidirectional communication, so the stream wrapped by `SslStream` would need to be both a readable and writeable stream.

Comment: @StephenCleary yes, but that's not what I'm asking about. I'm wondering if there's a way to have two SslStreams open against one Socket somehow where both have ReadWrite capabilities.

Comment: No, that's not possible. I don't know what you're trying to do; what you're asking to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: Converting an old flow that ensured reads was done separately in one background thread and writes one multiple threads (synchronized). Then it made sense.

Comment: You'd just need one `SslStream` and serialize the writes yourself.